# CommonJS function declaration scope good practice

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, commonjs

Is there a good practice for where you declare a function inside a CommonJS module in a case like this:

```
// function foo() { ... }

module.exports = function () {
   // function foo () { ... }

   return function () {
        // function foo () { ... }

        return foo();
   };
};
```

Where should `function foo {}` go ?
Of course I'm assuming you really have the choice between the 3 possibilities in your module code and that all of them would work properly as intended. I use a function as an example as I think it makes my question clearer, but it also goes for any code logic that can be encapsulated in those scopes.

Answer (score 0):

The point of module.exports is to make something available for import in other modules and that's really all it does.

This means that the same conventions that you would have used without module.exports apply here.